# getting a syntax error on elif statement?

Tags: python

**this is my full code i am not sure what the problem is**

```
option = 0

while option !=4:
```

> before i was repeating the similar codes along the print menu within each option selection but i changed it from while to if and elif but doesn't work?

```
    # Prints the menu to the screen


print("*** Menu *** \n")
print("1. Encrypt string")
print("2. Decrypt string")
print("3. Brute force decryption")
print("4. Quit \n")

option = int(input("What would you like to do [1,2,3,4]? "))
```

**this is the part where i used my print menu repeated code **

```
if option ==1:
   print("In command 1 - encrypt string \n")
   string = input("Please enter string to encrypt: ")
   offsetvalue = int(input("Please enter positive offset value: "))
    print("")

while offsetvalue > 26 or offsetvalue < 1:
      offsetvalue = int(input("Please enter a positive offset value between 1 - 26: "))
      Encryption = ""

for letter in string:
    encryption_num = ord(letter)
      encryption_num += offsetvalue

**# Loops the ASCII value**
if encryption_num > 126:
        encryption_num -= 94
        # adds it to the total string
        encryption_num = chr(encryption_num)
        Encryption += encryption_num
        # encrypted string to the screen
        print("\nEncrypted string:")
        print(Encryption)

elif option == 2:

        # prompts the user to input
        print("In command 2 - decrypt string \n")
        string = input("Please enter string to decrypt: ")
        offsetvalue = int(input("Please enter negative offset value: "))
        print("")

while offsetvalue < -26 or offsetvalue > -1:
      offsetvalue = int(input("Please enter negative offset value between -1 - -26: "))

    Decryption = ""

for letter in string:
    decryption_num = ord(letter)
    decryption_num += offsetvalue
         if decryption_num < 32:
            decryption_num += 94
            decryption_num = chr(decryption_num)
            Decryption += decryption_num

            print("\nDecrypted string:")
            print(Decryption)
```

problem seems to be here

```
elif option == 3:
     print("in command 3 -brute force \n")
     string = input("please enter string to decrypt: ")
     offsetvalue = -0
     while offsetvalue != -26:
     decryption_num = 0
     Decryption = ""

 while Decryption < len(letter):
      c = ord(string[decryption_num]) + offsetvalue
      if c < 0:
      c += 128
      decryption_num = chr(c)
      Decryption += decryption_str
      decryption_num += 1
      offsetvalue -= 1
      print ("\noffset", offsetvalue, "=Decrypted string:", Decryption)


    option = int(input("What would you like to do [1,2,3,4]? "))

#input error
elif option == 4:
        print ("\nGoodbye")
```

I tried my best to not sure where the problem is any help would be appreciated....

Comment: Can you post the *exact* error message? There are different kinds of syntax errors.

Comment: Can you also post the code before your `elif` condition?

Comment: And can you also make sure that the indentation in the posted code matches your original code?

Comment: Still no exact error message… We can’t help you that way

Comment: this is my whole code @poke.

Comment: yea this is my full code post @PaoloMoretti

Comment: @legend I’m not asking for the code, I’m asking for the *exact* error message. You say you have a syntax error; then tell us what the error says exactly.

Comment: it say's "invalid syntax" @poke

Comment: The code indentation looks messed up, the `while` block and the `for` block between option 2 and option 3 should be part of the second `elif`. Tip: For readability you should consider to split your code into smaller functions (for example, you can try to extract an `encrypt` and a `decrypt` function). Also choose a unique indentation style (you are mixing 2/4 spaces).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This makes not much sense:

```
elif option == 3:
        print("in command 3 -brute force \n")
        string = input("please enter string to decrypt: ")
        offsetvalue = -0
    while offsetvalue != -26:
```

It is this

```
elif option == 3:
        print("in command 3 -brute force \n")
        string = input("please enter string to decrypt: ")
        offsetvalue = -0
        while offsetvalue != -26:
```

or that

```
elif option == 3:
        print("in command 3 -brute force \n")
        string = input("please enter string to decrypt: ")
        offsetvalue = -0
while offsetvalue != -26:
```

Comment: yea i changed it @peterMmm

Comment: any better i posted the while code with proper indentation @PeterMmm